# Log4j: One log file per war

Tags: logging, log4j, classloader, war

Is this possible to set individual log files per war file basis? We have two application 'wars' each pertaining to a specific function and managed by different teams. We want to output individual war's log in its own log file. Please note that both these war use some common code and hence we can spearate at package level. Any inputs are appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you're deploying your application in JBoss, you can set a `<filter>` for the `<appender>`declared in `jboss-log4j.xml`. An [example from the JBoss Wiki](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SeparatingApplicationLogs):

```
<appender name="App1Log" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
  <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"></errorHandler>
  <param name="Append" value="false"/>
  <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.home.dir}/log/app1.log"/>
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %c{1} %m%n"/>
  </layout>
  <filter class="org.jboss.logging.filter.TCLFilter">
     <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/>
     <!-- value="app1.war" is incorrect. -->
     <param name="DeployURL" value="app1-exp.war"/>
  </filter>
```

Comment: I think that <param name="DeployURL" value="app1-exp" /> is enough, the TCLFilter only looks for substrings. This might help if you have a "versioned" war app1-x.y.z.war or if you are deploying from an IDE with artificial name app1:war.

Answer (score 3):

With log4j2 (log4j version 2.x) there is a useful lookup called [web:contextPath](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html#WebLookup), which can be used to specify the log file name, for example:

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/${web:contextPath}.log"
    filePattern="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/${web:contextPath}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
    ...
</RollingFile>
```

So every war file gets its own log file.

Comment: Don't forget to add dependency <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [log4j solution](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/log4jrepositoryselector) that works for JBoss.  It should work for other containers provided the wars use different class loaders.